# How to append the python output (using * and sep) in VIM buffer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, output

```
c = [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')]
```

I want to print `c` like this:

```
A,B,C
A,B,D
A,C,D
B,C,D
```

In python (3) the code to print this:

```
for i in c:
    print(*i,sep=',')
```

However it does not work when I add this in a vim function:

```
python3 << endpython
c = [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')]
for i in c:
    vim.current.buffer.append(*i,sep=",")
endpython
```

How can I append the above output in the vim buffer?

Comment: I guess that `:let r = map(c, 'join(v:val, ",")')` `:put=r` won't do it because your `c` variable is a python variable and not a viml variable?